# Get embedded resource file location

Tags: c#, embedded-resource

How can I get the location of embedded resource file?
I need to navigate chrome driver to the URL of an embedded html file for testing.

```
testDriver.Navigate().GoToUrl(fileLocation);
```

fileLocation should be c:\project folder\project\asset location within the project

If I use `System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location;` I get the location of the dll and not the project.

Comment: I don't think you can access an embedded resource with a browser directly. You will have to extract it to the filesystem and use the `file:///` protocol.

Comment: Its a selenium driver. I'm able to load the file using hard coded location, but I would like to do it programmatically

Comment: Can you edit your question and show us the code that you use to do it hard coded?